# return integer array from python to c++

Tags: c++, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
#include <include/python3.5m/Python.h>
#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
#include "numpy/arrayobject.h"
#include<iostream>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
   PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pFunc, *pArray, *pReturn;
   Py_Initialize();
   import_array();
   npy_intp dims[2]={4, 8};
   double c_arr[4][8];

   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
     for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
       c_arr[i][j] = i * 8 + j;

   pName = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault("pyFile");
   pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
   pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "pyFn");
   pArray = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(2, dims, NPY_DOUBLE, reinterpret_cast<void*>(c_arr));
   pReturn = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(pFunc, pArray, NULL);
   PyArrayObject *np_ret = reinterpret_cast<PyArrayObject*>(pReturn);
   int *c_out = reinterpret_cast<int*>(PyArray_DATA(np_ret));

   for (int i = 0; i < PyArray_SHAPE(np_ret)[0]; i++)
     printf("%d ", c_out[i]);
   printf("\n");

   return 0;
}
```

The list [23,11,26,2] is returned by **pyFn** in **pyFile.py** as an array: np.array([23,11,26,2]).

When I run this code the output is:
23 0 11 0

I had the following questions:

1. Why are the 0's appearing when C++ prints the array after casting it as an integer array? Should I cast c_out some other way?
2. Why do I get the warning *"converting to non-pointer type 'int' from NULL [-Wconversion-null] import_array()"* when I compile the code?

Comment: 1) Try casting to `long *` (or whatever is twice as big as `int` on your system) instead of `int *` (I might get downvoted for this).

Comment: And then change `"%d"` to `"%ld"`

Comment: Great MFisherKDX, it works! Not sure why I am not able to mark this as answered (I don't see the flag).

Comment: It's just a comment, so it's not really an "answer". If it works for you, you could post an answer. I didn't post as an answer because I wasn't sure and I also don't know how to solve problem #2.